# Javascript foreach (Multi array)

Tags: javascript, arrays

I got this javascript code wherein im trying  to access the "recommendedTo" array but, when im trying to access it via foreach it just returns as a [array] and not the exact values of the array.

What am i doing wrong?

```
let requestBody = {
    "recommendations":[
        {
            "book" : "12",
            "recommendedTo" : [
                {
                    "employeeId" : "22"
                },
                {
                    "employeeId" : "44"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "book": "13",
            "recommendedTo":[
                {
                    "employeeId": "2"
                },
                {
                    "employeeId": "3"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
};

let messageBody = {
    recommendations: []
};

if (Array.isArray(requestBody.recommendations)) {
    requestBody.recommendations.forEach(function(books, index) {
        messageBody.recommendations.push({
            book: books.book,
            recommended:[]
        }); 
        requestBody.recommendations[index].recommendedTo.forEach(function(book2, index2){
            messageBody.recommendations[index].recommended.push({
                employeeId: book2.employeeId,
            })
        });             
    });
}

console.log(messageBody)
```

Comment: Your code is accessing the `recommendedTo` array and adding that object in `recommended` array. So, what is wrong?

Comment: I guess you mean `messageBody.recommendations[index2].recommended.push()`.?

Comment: Your code works fine? Can you tell us what's wrong with it?

Comment: When im accessing the recommendedTo array, my output is [Array] instead of the employeeId values

Comment: @duplicated no it is not. Click on that to enlarge it?!

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/uFBuVGX expecting to have an output on the right side (base on the image) and im having an output (on the left side)

Answer (score 0):

A much cleaner solution

```
for(let recommendation of requestBody.recommendations){
    for(let recommendedTo of recommendation.recommendedTo){
        console.log(recommendation);
        console.log(recommendedTo);
    }
}
```

Comment: Im trying to stick with my expected output

Answer (score 0):

While your code works,this is actually a really good usecase for map:

```
 const messageBody = {
    recommendations: requestBody.recommendations.map(({book, recommendedTo}) => ({
        book,
        recommended: recommendedTo.map(({employeeId}) => ({employeeId}))
    }))
 };
```

Comment: still returns the recommended as [Array]

Comment: @duplicated try `console.log(messageBody.recommendations[0])`

Comment: yes, but my problem is. is there any way to access the recommended array using only foreach. so i can manipulate the outputs?